# Difference between pip3 install and sudo apt install

Tags: command-line, python

Can anyone tell me what the difference between installing a python module using pip3 install "something" and sudo apt install "something"?
Eg: sudo apt install python3-sklearn
and pip3 install scipy --user

Comment: `sudo apt install` tells the operating system to install apps/programs.  pip3 doesn't relate to the operating system, but is a package installer for python.

Answer (score 1):

The apt install downloads and installs applications for the operating system.

pip3 on the other hand installs a module for python, and not the operating system